# Node.js - Argon2 password hash crashes app after reaching 100% of CPU

Tags: javascript

My Node.js app has been crashing whenever I use Argon2 to hash a password. My app's CPU reaches 100% and forces it to restart. The problem occurs after the line :

```
argon2.hash(password, salt).then((hash) => {
```

I'm still a beginner in Node.js so this could be an obvious mistake from my side. Or not. Here is the whole code for that file:

```
var argon2 = require('argon2');

export class UserCrypto {
constructor() {
}

verify(hash, plain): Promise<boolean> {
    return argon2.verify(hash, plain);
}

hash(password): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
        argon2.generateSalt().then(salt => {
            argon2.hash(password, salt).then((hash) => {
                if (password == salt || salt == null) {
                    throw new Error("Sanity check on password failed")
                }
                resolve(hash);
            }).catch((err) => {
                reject(err);
            });
        }).catch((err) => {
            reject(err);
        });
    });
}
```

}

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

I had same issue with **Argon2**. This is the line where app crashes:

```
const hashedPassword = await argon2.hash(options.password)
```

And this was the produced Node error (Nodemon, in my case)

> [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Was using following **versions**:

> Node 16.14.0 LTS and Argon2 **0.28.2**

Switched back to Argon2 v.0.28.0 -> same issue.

Switched back to Argon2 v.**0.26.2** -> it **worked fine** (no crash and hash was generated)